# IvoryCKEditor / Symfony2 - Can't configure CKEditor toolbar

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm simply trying to configure my CKEditor's toolbar. [From the Docs:](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/usage/toolbar.html#custom-toolbar)

> Built-in Toolbars¶
>
> CKEditor provides three different packages with their own configurations (full, standard & basic). The bundle is shipped with the full edition but you can easily switch the toolbar configuration by using the full, standard or basic keyword as toolbar. You can configure it globally in your configuration:

```
# app/config/config.yml
ivory_ck_editor:
    configs:
        my_config:
            toolbar: full
```

> Or you can configure it your widget:

```
$builder->add('field', 'ckeditor', array(
    'config' => array('toolbar' => 'full'),
));
```

It seems pretty stupid, but neither of those does anything. The editor just always displays the 'full' toolbar. (I of course change `full` to either `standard` or `basic`)

Any Idea why? Or where I should start looking for the problem? Should I revert to another version of IvoryCKEditor (currently using 4.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set it as the `default_config`:

```
ivory_ck_editor:
    default_config: default
    configs:
        default:
            toolbar: basic
```